# c++11 std map add or replace and get the current with a single lookup

Tags: c++11, stl, containers

c++11 added several improvements to the containers that eliminate double lookups or move operations.

It seems to me that adding or replacing a current item should be one of these common operations, but I am failing to implement it with a single lookup and without pointless construction.

Emplace seems inspired from sets where the key is the value, but in maps we often would like to replace the value associated with a key.

Am I missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::(unordered_)map::insert_or_assign`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert_or_assign) is to be added in C++17.

Comment: thanks, yeap, this seems what is missing, but funny enough it does not have a form in which it might also return the current value

Comment: @gsf you can get the current value through the returned iterator, no?

Comment: @Rochet2 It is the new value, not the value that you replacing (if any).